# How to add custom model field annotations to render in the view ASP.NET, Core 3, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Is it possible, and if so how, to add custom model field annotations to be rendered in a specific way in the view?

Quick example:

Here is a simple ContactUs Model class:

```
namespace Core.Business.Models
{
    public class ContactUsModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is then rendered in the view like this:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Telephone" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input asp-for="Telephone" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Message" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea rows="8" asp-for="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Now, what I would really like is to be able to add custom annotations to the model class that render in a pre-desinged manor:

e.g.: ContactUs Model class:

```
namespace Core.Business.Models
{
    public class ContactUsModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        [CustomTag(Description="Please enter your message here, the more information you can provide the better.")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then on the view I can use a "tag helper" to display this annotation:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Message" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea rows="8" asp-for="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>

        **@html.MyTag(...here would be pulled in the custom tag annotation value....)**

        <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is, I could annotate the Model class with "help" information which could be rendered on the page as a help text or a "i" icon which when clicked pops up the help text.

Possible?

Thanks

Ro

Answer (score 0):

Are custom tag helpers useful here?

You can create a custom tag helper when you want a layout or properties that are not already defined - such as a bootstrap CARD

It is also possible to extend existing tag helpers such as an anchor by creating your custom tag helper based on the anchor tag helper.

You can also create a base class tag helper that has common functionality to be shared by all of your custom tag helpers

A simple example

```
/// <summary>
/// Render simple text : <textonly resource-name="RegisteredAddress" resource-list="Model" class="text-dark font-weight-bold"></textonly>
/// </summary>
public class TextonlyTagHelper : TagHelperEx
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // we need a resource in order to proceed
        if (this.Resource != null)
        {
            // render a html span
            output.TagName = "span";

            // with this tooltip
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("title", this.Resource.Tooltip);

            // and this text
            output.Content.SetContent(this.Resource.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will see if I can look into your example of custom tag helpers extension and see if this resolves my issues. Thanks again